# How to use pyarrow record batch to communicate across different processes or even different hosts

Tags: pyarrow

I read about recordBatch in pyarrow and am very interested. (I am a novice in the pyarrow world). I am wondering if I could use it to communicate between two different processes or different hosts. I am confused because all the examples/documentation I would find online are use cases within the same process, e.g. https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/ipc.html and https://wesmckinney.com/blog/arrow-streaming-columnar/ Basically, they are doing this:

```
sink = pa.BufferOutputStream()
writer = pa.ipc.new_stream(sink, batch.schema)
writer.write_batch(batch)
writer.close()
source = sink.getvalue()
reader = pa.ipc.open_stream(source)
# reader do job...
```

Two questions:

1. If I have two different processes or two different hosts, one writes and another one reads, how do I pass the "source" or some kind of handle? I tried with a vanilla file but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I am doing sth wrong. For example,

```
writer = pa.ipc.new_file('tmp.record_batch', batch.schema)
writer.write_batch(batch) 
# works so far, but next:
reader = pa.ipc.open_file('tmp.record_batch')

ArrowInvalid: Not an Arrow file
```

2. Is there a SWMR (single-write-multiple-non-blocking-reader) mode?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The examples are demonstrating in-process for simplicity, but they are working with the Arrow IPC format, which you can send between processes or machines. Think of this in terms of a Parquet, Avro, or CSV file - you can write this out in one process, then read it in another process. It's up to you how these processes communicate otherwise.

For your attempt, you need to close the file to write out the footer before you can open it in another process. You could also try the [stream format](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/ipc.html#using-streams) which doesn't depend on a footer and should be readable incrementally (assuming you flush the file each time). This may even work over something like a domain socket depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

However, it sounds like you're interested in something more like a client-server setup? In that case, [Arrow Flight](https://arrow.apache.org/cookbook/py/flight.html) may be more appropriate, especially once you have two different hosts. Flight is an RPC framework specialized for Arrow data transfer.

Comment: Thanks li.davidm! Now I understand I do need to close a file, unless I work with streams (and flush them), thanks for clarifying that. I guess I would appreciate a non-trivial example of communications between two separate processes, or two different hosts, because (due to my lack of understanding) I wasn't able to generalize the in-process example to these new cases. If, for example, I need to/have to invoke Arrow Flight for this purpose, that would be good to know, too.

Comment: Regarding a server-client set up, for example I was reading this https://arrow.apache.org/cookbook/py/flight.html Suppose I do: server put data to flight, flight save to parquet (which means to disk), client request a list of available files, then reads them. I guess I would like to understand how is this better than server writes data to new parquet files periodically, client scan that folder, and pick up some files from there? (Let's say the two hosts are connected and one can read another's disk by /nfs/another_host.)